# how to search string inside another string in system verilog?

Tags: system-verilog

If I want to know if string `a` is included string `qwerty`, is there an easy way to do this in system verilog? Like below code in C?

```
a.strstr("qwerty");
```

Comment: Even though this question was answered long time ago, I thought it'd be useful to put a link to this [other related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44948561/system-verilog-regular-expressions), which received a very comprehensive/useful answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `svlib` library from Verilab that wraps the C functions we know and love in SystemVerilog functions. It provides its own `Str` class that can tell you if a string contains a certain substring:

```
Str my_str = Str::create(a);
if my_str.first("qwerty")
  $display("found it");
```

You can find `svlib` at [this location](http://www.verilab.com/resources/svlib/)

Comment: UVM also provides a similar facility to do regexp matching using the DPI, in case you're already using that. Have a look at the functions in `uvm_svcmd_dpi.svh`.

Comment: @ Tudor Timi- whihch one of the functions?

Answer (score 4):

currently i do it this way, it works. but i am wondering if there is a better way...

```
int len = a.len();
for( int i =0; i < len;i++) begin
    if(a.substr(i,i+6-1) =="qwerty")
       $display("found it");
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on the answer by [awill](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27289272/253127) I coded these two functions:

```
function int contains(string a, string b);
  // checks if string A contains string B
  int len_a;
  int len_b;
  len_a = a.len();
  len_b = b.len();
  $display("a (%s) len %d -- b (%s) len %d", a, len_a, b, len_b);
  for( int i=0; i<len_a; i++) begin
    if(a.substr(i,i+len_b-1) == b)
         return 1;
  end
  return 0;
endfunction


function int startswith(string a, string b);
  // checks if string A starts-with string B
  int len_b;
  len_b = b.len();
  if(a.substr(0, len_b-1) == b)
    return 1;
  return 0;
endfunction
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    module test;
      string mainString = "hello world";
      string subString = "rld";

      initial begin
        for (int i=0; i<mainString.len()-subString.len()+1; i++) begin
          if( mainString.substr(i,i+subString.len()-1) == subString ) begin
            $display("\n it Contraints \n");
          end
        end
      end
  endmodule
```