# System verilog Regular expressions

Tags: regex, system-verilog

I understood that System verilog does not have very good regular expression support inbuilt.

How can I check in systemVerilog that a srting matches to the following regular expressions:
 "\d+(ns|ps|us)"

Comment: Try `result = uvm_pkg::uvm_re_match("[0-9]+[npu]s",str);`, or if the method requires a full string match, use `".*[0-9][npu]s.*"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a number of different options.

Some simulators already support a set of SystemVerilog string method extensions that handle regular expressions such as str.match() and str.search().

```
result = str.match(“pattern”); // returns true if the pattern is matched with the str.
```

If you are using the UVM, there is a DPI routine that does the same thing

```
result = uvm_pkg::uvm_re_match(“pattern”,str);
```

There are number of other packages out there such as SVunit that also provide the DPI routines for you.

Comment: Will `str.match(...)` be part of the next standard?

Comment: The next revision of the standard will be 1800-2017 and does not contain any enhancements -  only clarifications and corrections.